# setting up ssh-copy-id on ubuntu

Tags: permissions, ssh

I'm trying to setup ssh-copy-id on ubuntu I need a second opinion on this, is this a missing .pub path or wrong settings for ssh

```
sammy@samuel-pc:~$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
cat: /home/sammy/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: Permission denied
sammy@samuel-pc:~$ ssh-copy-id root@67.205.154.128

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: failed to open ID file '/home/sammy/.pub': No such file
    (to install the contents of '/home/sammy/.pub' anyway, look at the -f option)
sammy@samuel-pc:~$ cd .ssh
-bash: cd: .ssh: Permission denied


sammy@samuel-pc:~$ sudo ls -l ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
[sudo] password for sammy: 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sammy sammy 397 Jul 12 20:25 /home/sammy/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

I've also tried sshing from my computer, but the authentication was broken and I tried to fix it but it fails

```
samuel@samuel-pc:~$ ssh-copy-id sammy@pluscolor.co.ke
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
sammy@pluscolor.co.ke's password: 
sh: 1: cannot create .ssh/authorized_keys: Permission denied
```

Result from `sudo ls -lsa ~/.ssh`

```
sammy@samuel-pc:~$ sudo ls -lsa ~/.ssh
[sudo] password for sammy: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for sammy: 
total 28
4 drw-rw-rw- 2 sammy sammy 4096 Jul 13 21:25 .
4 drwxr-xr-x 9 sammy sammy 4096 Jul 19 23:55 ..
4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 sammy sammy  790 Jul 13 21:35 authorized_keys
4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 sammy sammy 1675 Jul 12 20:25 id_rsa
4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 sammy sammy  397 Jul 12 20:25 id_rsa.pub
4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 sammy sammy 1024 Jul 13 12:48 .id_rsa.pub.swp
4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 sammy sammy  222 Jul 12 20:21 known_hosts
```

and result for `ls -ld ~/.ssh`

```
sammy@samuel-pc:~$ ls -ld ~/.ssh
drw-rw-rw- 2 sammy sammy 4096 Jul 13 21:25 /home/sammy/.ssh
```

How can I get right access for ssh in the server?

Comment: please [edit] your question and add the result of `ls -lsa ~/.ssh`

Comment: WTF don't you have permissions to your own `~/.ssh`?

Comment: `sudo ls -lsa ~/.ssh` might be better. did you create your keys using `root` user?

Comment: Can you add the output of: `ls -ld ~/.ssh` too please?

Comment: added the code @Ravexina

Comment: use `chmod u+x ~/.ssh` then try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command should fix the permission problem of your `~/.ssh` folder

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

- This will allow read/write/execution to the folder - only for the owner (yourself)
- execution means - change directory

The following command will set the correct permission of the files inside the `~/.ssh` folder

```
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/*
```

- The files in `~/.ssh` folder should have *owner read-only* permission
- `chmod 400` set the *owner read-only* permission

After you fix the `~/.ssh` folder/files permission  you can try to execute again the `ssh-copy-id` command

Comment: thanks it worked. Can I use chmod 400 foldername on the other folder... where I store images I can't write data to is using sftp previously could.

Comment: You can't execute `chmod 400` on folders, as it will remove the option to access the files in the directory (e.g. using change dir), you can set `chmod 700 dir-name`

Comment: I tried chmod 700 on the folder now when I try to go into it using filezilla I get Command: cd "gallery"
Error: Directory /home/sammy/revamp/gallery: permission denied
Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing

Comment: @SamuelMuiruri - I think that you are asking a new question, if so, please open a new question, and provide all relevant details (e.g. I'm trying to copy files using `filezilla`, from computerA to computerB, from folderA to folderB, the directory/file permissions on folderA is ... `ls -lsa folderA`. I get the following error from filezilla... etc...

Comment: @Yaron, is there any flag to tell ssh-copy-id to change correct the permissions as it runs?

Comment: @newbie - `ssh-copy-id` manual doesn't include such flag

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `ssh-copy-id` you need to have ssh (id_rsa) key files generated. In my case I accidentally generated key with `sudo` which resulted in `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files generated under `/root/.ssh/` instead of `/home/user/.ssh/`. So afterwards trying to accomplish `ssh-copy-id someuser@somehost` I've got:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: failed to open ID file '/home/user/.pub': No such file
(to install the contents of '/home/user/.pub' anyway, look at the -f option)
```

The temptation is to use `-f` option, however real solution is simple: just generate ssh private key without sudo:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Typically below `~/.ssh/` file content should work:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ll .ssh/
total 28
drwx------  2 user group 4096 Dec 30 16:17 ./
drwxr-xr-x 15 user group 4096 Dec 30 16:17 ../
-rw-------  1 user group 1773 Dec 30 17:23 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 user group 1679 Jan  1  2016 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 user group  399 Jan  1  2016 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 user group 2436 Dec 30 16:17 known_hosts
user@ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score -1):

So your issue is caused by a few errors in your file permissions.

**First:** Your directory has no executable flag which means your system can not actually change into it and access the files inside of it. This should fix that.

```
chmod +x ~/.ssh
```

Afterwards you will need to adjust your permissions of the files of the public keys and private keys, which should only be readable by your user and not anything by any other user. Which you accomplish with:

```
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/*
```

This should fix your issue. Sometimes ssh is really picky and can cause still errors if your `/home/user` is still writable by the group/others. So for safty remove write permission from the home for group and others aswell.

```
chmod go-w ~/
```

This should fix your issues.

Comment: it didn't fix my issue